# How do I display data from my json file that match my filters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, react-props

I'm creating a multi steps form in React and I want a page (Filters.jsx) in my form, that returns me all the menus name (contained in data.json) that matches my filters ( beaf, chicken, vegetables),  but I don't kow how to do that.

```
import React from "react";
export default function Filter() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <div className=" w-full mx-2 flex-1">
        <div className="font-bold h-6 mt-3 text-gray-600  leading-8 uppercase ">
          {" "}
          Norms
        </div>

        <tbody className="bg-white my-2 p-1 flex borer border-gray-200 rounded text-gray-500">
          <tr>
            <td className="font-bold h-8 mt-5 leading-8 uppercase ">
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="beaf" className="w-8 h-3" /> beaf
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="chicken" className="w-8 h-3" />
                chicken
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="vegetables" className="w-8 h-3" />
                vegetables
              </td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the link of my sandbox ( browse /menu/form to see the form): https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-river-ktoic8?

What I tried:

```
export default function Filters() {

    //Filters events
    const ref = [
        { name: "beaf" },
        { name: "chicken" },
        { name: "vegetables" }
    ]

    const [norms, setNorms] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        setNorms(ref);
    }, []);


    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, checked } = e.target;
        let tempR = norms.map((r) =>
            r.name === name ? { ...r, isChecked: checked } : r
        );
        setNorms(tempR);
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <form className="form w-100">
                {
                    norms.map((e, index) => (
                        <div className="form-check" key={index}>
                            <input
                                type="checkbox"
                                className="form-check-input"
                                name={e.name}
                                checked={e?.isChecked || false}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <label className="form-check-label ms-2">{e.name}</label>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </form >
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: What have you tried? The `Filters` component looks pretty empty. You'll need some state to hold the filter values, and then filter and map the JSON data into the table. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've tried to use useState([]) and useEffect  but doesn't seem working

Comment: State would hold whatever filter values you need to filter by, and I don't see much use for an `useEffect` hook. Filter and map the JSON data to JSX. SO isn't a code writing service, so we can't fix, diagnose, or debug, what you haven't created or tried yet.

Comment: I modified the question, I add what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using an object or Map to hold the filter values where the filter name is the key and the checked value is the value.

```
const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState({});
```

Create a handler that sets the checked value for a specific input by name.

```
const changeHandler = (e) => {
  const { name, checked } = e.target;
  setFilters((filters) => ({
    ...filters,
    [name]: checked
  }));
};
```

Render the inputs and set the `checked` prop from state.

```
{["beef", "chicken", "vegetables"].map((name) => (
  <td key={name}>
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={filters[name]}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        name={name}
        className="w-8 h-3"
      />
      {name}
    </label>
  </td>
))}
```

And then filter/map the data, all inline.

```
import data from "../../data.json";

...

{data
  .filter((item) => {
    // get array of enabled filter keys
    const filterEntries = Object.entries(filters)
      .filter(([, value]) => Boolean(value))
      .map(([key]) => key);

    // some filter enabled
    if (filterEntries.length) {
      // check proteins
      if (filters.beef || filters.chicken) {
        return item.dishes.some((dish) =>
          filterEntries.includes(dish.meat)
        );
      }

      // check vegetables
      if (filters.vegetables) {
        return item.dishes.some((dish) => !!dish.vegetables);
      }
    }

    // no filter enabled, return all elements
    return true;
  })
  .map((item) => (
    <tr key={item.id}>
      .... map data item properties here ...
    </tr>
  ))}
```

[image: Edit divine-fire-735rty]

Comment: Hi, if I had an array : `const= ["vegetable1", "vegetable2"...., "vegetable50"]`  (if this veg is seleted then print my menu ) and I want to apply my filter. Can I do : 
`{data
    .filter((item) => { ...
        if (filterEntries.length) {
            if (filters.data.map((d) => d)) {
                return item.norms.some((d) =>
                    filterEntries.includes(d.name)
                );

            }
        }
        return true;
    })
    .map((item) => (
...
    ))}`

Comment: @Zokulko Do you mean something the `dish.vegetables` value is an array of vegetables? And the user is presented with a list of vegetables to filter by?

Comment: Nope I add something else. vegetables was not an array of vegetables. This time I want to add an array of vegetables called `const veg= ["vegetable1", "vegetable2"...., "vegetable50"]`. The user will  apply filters among this list of vegetables

Comment: @Zokulko Sorry, I'm not quite understanding what you are asking. Is this effectively a new issue/question you are asking for help with?

Comment: Not really. I was wondering if this time if I get an array called `const veg= ["vegetable1", "vegetable2"...., "vegetable50"]` and the user is presented with a list of vegetables to filter by. Does my proposition code work? I wanted to avoid all the if.

Comment: @Zokulko Where is this `veg` array defined and where are you trying to use it? The different/various `if` statements are because the menu item data has these as "categories". If what you are asking is if `dish.vegetable` (*being a single vegetable*) can be compared against an array of vegetables, the answer is yes, it can. Something like `if (filters.vegetables) { return filters.vegetables.includes(dish.vegetable)) }`.